# jQuery mobile. PhoneGap, dynamic module loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova, requirejs

I'm creating a PhoneGap application which uses jQuery Mobile, and I'm currently having problems with dynamically loading in javascript with $.getScript();

The below fails:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#index',function() {
               $.getScript("/assets/js/alert.js",function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){});
});
```

However...when I call it in over HTTP.. works:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#index',function() {
               $.getScript("http://testdomain.com/assets/js/alert.js",function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){});
});
```

The following thread on Google Groups is relevant, however proved to be fruitless for me:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/LkIN97HYX5k

Ideally, I need a lazy load of certain script files when jQuery mobile brings in new pages. For any one familiar, new pages neither need headers or footer of data as they are generated on the fly:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> The simplest approach when building a jQuery Mobile site is to
>   reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every
>   page. If you need to load in specific scripts or styles for a
>   particular page, we recommend binding logic to the pageinit event
>   (details below) to run necessary code when a specific page is created
>   (which can be determined by its id attribute, or a number of other
>   ways). Following this approach will ensure that the code executes if
>   the page is loaded directly or is pulled in and shown via Ajax.

What I'm wondering, is firstly, if anyone else has experienced problems with jQuery's getScript in this manner, or if there is a workaround. Secondly, and suggestions on loaders for dynamic javascript which will work within the confines of PhoneGap and jQuery mobile. From reading around, Require.js seems to be along the right path, but isn't fully PhoneGap compatible.

Hope I'm making sense.